# Python3: module 'x' has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Python import statement is confusing the heck out of me. Can someone help me clear this up?

file tree looks like this

```
root
+- notebook.ipynb
+- lib/
  +- basestation_config.py
  +- config.py
+- config/
  +- valence_pod.json
  +- etc…
```

in `config.py` I have:

```
import json
import os

default_config_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'config'))

def read_filepath(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r") as read_file:
        return json.load(read_file)

def read(filename):
    filepath = os.path.join(default_config_path, filename) + '.json'
    return read_filepath(filepath)
```

in `basestation_config.py` I have:

```
import config as config
# … a buncha class libraries, including BasestationConfig
def read_basestation_config(config_name = 'valence_pod'):
    return BasestationConfig(config.read(config_name))
```

in `notebook.ipynb` I have a test cell:

```
import lib.basestation_config as bsc
bs_config = bsc.read_basestation_config()
display(bs_config)
```

and when I run it, I get:

```
<module 'config' (namespace)>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f2942fb5fb2d> in <module>
      1 import lib.basestation_config as bsc
----> 2 bs_config = bsc.read_basestation_config()
      3 display(bs_config)

/mnt/eng_store/pod/logs/embedded/utils/logutils/indot-py/lib/basestation_config.py in read_basestation_config(config_name)
    270 def read_basestation_config(config_name = 'valence_pod'):
    271     print(config)
--> 272     return BasestationConfig(config.read(config_name))

AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute ‘read’
```

Comment: The message is telling you that the 'config' module you imported does not have a method called 'read'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `import config`, Python is using the *config* folder (the one with the JSON file) instead of the `lib/config.py` module. You can check this by printing `config.__path__` after importing it:

```
import config as config
print(config.__path__)
# _NamespacePath(['/path/to/root/config'])
```

`_NamespacePath` indicates that the folder *config* is being treated as an [implicit Python package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification), it does not contain an `__init__.py` like a [regular Python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), but the name matches the "config" being imported.

> While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory
>   in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.

Your setup falls under bullet #3, as `<directory>/config` matches the `import config` target. You might then wonder what is `<directory>` here? That depends on the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), stored in `sys.path`, which is a list of all the directories where Python will look for import targets. When you run your test script under *root*, the *root* directory is then added to your `sys.path`.

> The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path.

Check it by adding this before `import config` in *basestation_config.py*:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
# ['/path/to/root', ... ]

import config as config
```

That explains the why. To fix this, you can do this:

1. Rename the *config* folder to something else (ex. *jsonfiles*), just to prevent future errors like this and to distinguish it from the *config.py* module
2. Change *lib* to follow the [regular Python package structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), by adding a `__init__.py` file under *lib* to clearly mark it as a package.

   ```
   lib
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── basestation_config.py
   └── config.py
   ```
3. Lastly, make it clear in *basestation_config.py* that you are importing the *config.py* in the same directory.

   ```
   from . import config as config    
   print(config.__file__) 
   # /path/to/lib/config.py
   ```

Note that, before doing step 3, if you added the `print(config.__path__)` earlier, **make sure to remove it** after applying the corrected codes, since it's mostly likely not available on your *config.py* (you might get "*AttributeError: module 'lib.config' has no attribute `__path__`*").

It should now work after those changes.